Powershell in bat file closing console
I have a bat file that normalizes several audio files in one folder.
I create txt files with the same names as the audio files and I need to delete some lines from a txt file that will be used to eliminate custom tags in audio files.
Note:
The variable "Filename!.txt" will have several different values
Example: ACDC - Jailbreak or ACDC - TNT... but they will all have the character "-" separating the singer's name from the song's name.
I use the command below to run powershell via bat file (with double quotes at the beginning and end of the gci command):
"%systemroot%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command "gci !Filename!.txt | foreach { (cat $_.fullname | ? {$_ -match 'METADATA|title|encoder' }) | set-content $_.fullname}"

error result:
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find a positional parameter that accepts the argument '-'.
In line:1 character:1
+ gci ACDC - Jailbreak.txt | foreach { (cat $_.fullname | ?  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Code:
md "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Temp_normalizing_lufs"    ------> temp folder audio files being normalized   
pushd "%Userprofile%\Desktop\µudios LUFS"                 ------> folder with the original audio files
                                                                                                     __
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('where .:*.mp3 ^|findstr /vi "_LOUDNORM  _EBU"') DO (                          |                
  SET "filename=%%~na"                                                                                  |
  ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "%%a" -af "[0:a]loudnorm=print_format=summary" -f null NUL 2> "%%~na.log"      |   
  @FOR /F "tokens=3" %%b IN ('FINDSTR /C:"Input Integrated" "%%~na.log"') DO (SET II=%%b)               |
  @FOR /F "tokens=4" %%b IN ('FINDSTR /C:"Input True Peak" "%%~na.log"') DO (SET ITP=%%b)               |  set original audio files values  
  @FOR /F "tokens=3" %%b IN ('FINDSTR /C:"Input LRA" "%%~na.log"') DO (SET ILRA=%%b)                    |  to use as parameters in loudnorm
  @FOR /F "tokens=3" %%b IN ('FINDSTR /C:"Input Threshold" "%%~na.log"') DO (SET IT=%%b)                |
  @FOR /F "tokens=3" %%b IN ('FINDSTR /C:"Target Offset" "%%~na.log"') DO (SET TO=%%b)                  |
  DEL "%%~na.log"                                                                                     __|

  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%b IN ('ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams a -show_entries "stream=bit_rate,sample_rate" -of "csv=p=0" "!filename!.mp3"')     ----> getting the sample rate and bitrate of the original audio file to use as parameters in loudnorm
  DO (  
      ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "!filename!.mp3" -an -f ffmetadata -vsync vfr "!filename!.txt"

      "%systemroot%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command "gci !filename!.txt | foreach { (cat $_.fullname | ? { $_ -match 'METADATA|title|encoder' }) | set-content $_.fullname }"
      
      ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "!filename!.mp3" -c:a copy -map_metadata -1 -vsync vfr "!filename!_not_tags.mp3"
      ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "!filename!_not_tags.mp3" -i "!filename!.txt" -codec copy -id3v2_version 3 -map_metadata 1 -id3v2_version 3 -vsync vfr "!filename!_with_tags.mp3"    
      ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "!filename!_with_tags.mp3" -af "loudnorm=linear=true:I=!_vLUF!:LRA=11:tp=!_vPEAK!:measured_I=!II!:measured_LRA=!ILRA!:measured_tp=!ITP!:measured_thresh=!IT!:offset=!TO!:print_format=summary" -c:v copy -id3v2_version 3 -metadata disc="" -metadata comment="" -metadata lyrics-eng="" -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)" -acodec mp3 -b:a %%c -ar:a %%b "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Normalizando_lufs\!filename!.mp3"
     
      del /q "C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\µudios LUFS\!filename!.txt"
      del /q "C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\µudios LUFS\!filename!_not_tags.mp3"
      del /q "C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\µudios LUFS\!filename!_with_tags.mp3"
     )
  ENDLOCAL
)

xcopy "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Temp_normalizing_lufs\*.mp3" "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Normalized µudios Lufs\LOUDNORM\MP3\LUFS %-10.0%" /y /s /i   ----> copying the audio files from the temporary folder to the final folder

                                                                __
del /q "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Temp_normalizing_lufs\*.*"    |
rmdir "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Temp_normalizing_lufs" /s /q   |  Removing the temporary folder from the desktop
                                                                __|

The "-" character in the file names in the variable, is it a special character that needs escaping and is this causing the error? If so, how to escape this character?
Note:
The powershell command is inside a for loop that is executed inside SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

There is no command DO. That is part of the FOR command, and needs to be moved up to the previous line, along with the opening parenthesis which follows it, in order for it to be seen as part of the FOR command. Alternatively, you can move the closing parenthesis from the line above, to precede DO, i.e. )DO, (or more correctly ) DO), to achieve the same thing.

Try ...gci '!Filename!'.txt ^|...
So. Like:
powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command gci '!Filename!'.txt ^| foreach {(cat $_.fullname ^| ? {$_ -match 'METADATA^|title^|encoder'}) ^| set-content $_}

See: Using multi-line

it didn't work, the console screen closes and the bat ends!... but I found the solution and posted it in my question.

The problem was:
1 - The variable created is !filename! and in the command was !Filename! with the first letter in uppercase character;
2 - I put the variable in single quotes '!filename!.txt'.
Correct command:
"%systemroot%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -command "gci '!filename!.txt' | foreach { (cat $_.fullname | ? { $_ -match 'METADATA|title|encoder' }) | set-content $_.fullname}"

